# how to redirect a static pdf file which is in current directory as a response

Tags: r

I have used `include_html(req, res)`
and `include_file()` but there is an error like "serializers must be closures:null"

```
#* get /etf
aa<-function(args,res) #localhost:8000/etf?args=true
{
path="users/a.pdf"
path11="users/output.html"
#include_file(path, res, content-type = "application/pdf")
include_html(path11,res)}

#* @assets .
list()
#* @assets . /etf
list()

output.html:
<html> <script type="text/javascript"> window.location = './etf/a.pdf '; </script> </html>
```

Comment: Please give the precise error message and a little more context

Comment: Error in self$serve(req, res) : Serializers must be closures: 'null'